# Is there a way to set the minimum length of a TextInput in React-Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to set the minimum length of textInput in React Native, but I couldn't find the event for min length in React Native tutorial.

Is there any way to set the min length of textInput?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Add a `onChange` handler and validate value for minimum length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use _onPress like below

```
_onPress = () => {
        if (this.state.value.length < 5) { 
          Alert.alert('Alert', 'Please type more then 5 words');
        return;
      }
        this.props.onPress(this.ref._lastNativeText);
        this.ref.setNativeProps({ text: '' });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to limit the length of words without using Alert.

Comment: You just remove Alert

Answer (score 1):

As commented,

> Add a onChange handler and validate value for minimum length

#### Idea

- You will have to add `onChange` handler to do custom validation as there is no direct way.
- In this function, you can check for length and validate it.

Following code also implements following behavior:

- Input can accept anything but has `minLength` is 6.
- If input is not valid, border changes to red to signify error.

  - Error is shown only if input is not being changes (*i.e. does not have focus*)
  - Error is not shown if value is completely removed. Just for case when you have optional field.

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/70db49ua/11/)

```js
class MyInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
   value: '',
      isValid: true,
      hasFocus: false
    }
  }
  
  onChange(event) {
   const value = event.target.value;
    const isValid = value.length >= (this.props.minLength || 0) ||value === ''
   this.setState({ value, isValid })
  }
  
  onClick() {
   this.setState({ hasFocus: true })
  }
  
  onBlur() {
   this.setState({ hasFocus: false })
  }
  
  render() {
   const { isValid, hasFocus } = this.state;
    return (
    <div>
      <input
        type='text'
        className={ isValid || hasFocus ? '' : 'error'}
        onChange={ this.onChange.bind(this) }
        onClick={ this.onClick.bind(this) }
        onBlur={ this.onBlur.bind(this) }
      />
    </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyInput minLength={6} />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onChangeText()` function, You can do as mentioned below:

```
const maxLengthInput = set your limit // 60;
const currentLength=this.state.text.length;
this.setState({
  textLength: maxLengthInput - currentLength,
  text:inputValue
});
```

So, you can use `the this.state.textLength` in your component.

Comment: *Is there any way to set the **min** length of textInput?*

Answer (score 0):

The minLength prop is now part of React Native:
use the following in your code.

```
<TextInput value={this.state.text} minLength={4} />
```

You're good to go!

Comment: Isn't this the exact opposite of what the question is asking? This will set a max length but not enforce a minimum length.